# UIButton shadow layer effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, shadow

I am creating a UIButton similar to this image:
[image]

I tried it by using following code:

```
+(void)createShadowOnView:(UIView *)view color:(UIColor *)color width:(CGFloat)width height:(CGFloat)height shadowOpacity:(CGFloat)shadowOpacity andShadowRadius:(CGFloat)radius{

    view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    view.layer.shadowColor = color.CGColor;
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(width,height);
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity;
    [view.layer setShadowRadius:radius];
}
```

I was able to achieve this:

[image]

I want shadow effect on Button to be kept only on bottom part.

How can I achieve desired effect.

Comment: problem not in this method , some where else check once

Comment: How are you drawing the button, aside from the shadow? Is it an image or are you drawing it with Core Graphics or something else?

Comment: I am creating it via storyboard then creating border, rounded corner and shadow programmatically.

Comment: you might use pod .. easier https://github.com/AlexHsieh/ButtonAppearance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only issue with your code is you missed to set background colour for your sign up button. Use this code,

```
self.signUpButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[UIView createShadowOnView:self.signUpButton color:[UIColor lightGrayColor] width:0 height:2 shadowOpacity:0.3 andShadowRadius:0];
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should set view's backgroundcolor, so the title has no shadow, you can set view.layer.shadowOffset to change the shadow size.

```
UIButton *customBTn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
customBTn.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
customBTn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 50);
[customBTn setTitle:@"Sign Up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customBTn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:168/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
customBTn.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1/255.0 green:168/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
customBTn.layer.borderWidth = 2;
customBTn.layer.cornerRadius = 25;
customBTn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
customBTn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,8);
customBTn.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9;
[self.view addSubview:customBTn];
```

**Output :-**

[image]

Comment: I have created button in storyboard and already tried this but the thing is that I only want to drop shadow on bottom line of button not on whole button. It is creating on whole.

Comment: yestday i misread your request(just make title no shadow),if you only want to make the bottom line has shadow, you can set the shaowoffset.hope can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Preview:

[image]

Code:

```
UIButton *buttonWithShadow = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[buttonWithShadow setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 300.0f, 50.0f)];
[buttonWithShadow setTitle:@"SIGN UP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonWithShadow setTitle:@"SIGN UP" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[buttonWithShadow.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f]];
[buttonWithShadow setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f/255.0 green:168.0f/255.0 blue:244.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonWithShadow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f/255.0 green:168.0f/255.0 blue:244.0f/255.0 alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setBorderWidth:2.0f];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setCornerRadius:(buttonWithShadow.frame.size.height / 2.0f)];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setShadowOpacity:0.3f];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setShadowRadius:0.0f];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f,2.0f)];
[buttonWithShadow.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
[self.view addSubview:buttonWithShadow];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was actually missing to set background color of the button.